# CALayer position and anchorpoint

Tags: ios, calayer

I've already done a lot of work with animating CALayers, but I never really understood the positioning system completely. Most of the time I just try, how it turns out.

I know the `anchorPoint` of an implicit `CALayer` is the center of the parent `UIView`.
Meaning I have to subtract or add 160 to each value I want to animate on the x-axix, or 284 (this does vary due to NavigationBars) on the y-axis.

But I got into a situation which was kinda weird in my eyes. I'll explain it here:

I created a bar on the bottom of the screen, which is 44px heigh. I created it with this `frame`: `CGRectMake(0.0, 568.0, 320.0, 44.0)`. `524` would be the normal position, `568` is the hidden position.
The animation did not work with these values, neither adding or subtracting 284 solved the issue. I had to experiment a bit, to get it working, this is the working version of my code.

```
CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position.y"];
[animation setFromValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:546.0]];
[animation setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:590.0]];
[animation setDuration:0.3];
[[self layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"inAnimation"];
[[self layer] setPosition:CGPointMake(160.0, 590.0)];
```

This animates the `UIView` out of the visible area. Why do I have to use `546` instead of `524` for my `fromValue` and `590` for my `toValue`. This is a difference of 22px. Why?

Still a miracle.

Comment: What is stored in keyPath? And not working means no animation or the result didn't come out as you expected?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I've added the keyPath. The animation did work, but was not working as expected (shifted on the y-axis).